# How many positive integers less than 10,000 have at most two different digits?

Tags: combinatorics

Hi I've been working on this problem, and don't know how to solve it.

Here it is:
How many positive integers less than 10,000 have at most two different digits.

I think this problem has something to do with the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I'm not entirely sure. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty elementary. See the following link for an explanation.
https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2004_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_4

Answer (score 1):

The numbers of at most $N$ digits having at most two distinct digits are of three types:

1. numbers having one distinct digit,
2. numbers having two distinct non-zero digits,
3. numbers having the digit $0$, which may not be the first digit, and a non-zero digit.

Enumerating these gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
9\sum_{n=1}^N 1+\binom{9}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N(2^n-2)+9\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(2^n-1)&=9N+36(2^{N+1}-2-2N)+9(2^N-1-N)\\
&=81\cdot2^N-72N-81\\
&=81(2^N-1)-72N
\end{aligned}
$$
possibilities.  Note that when $N=1$ or $2$, all numbers have at most two distinct digits, and, indeed, the formula gives the results $9$ and $99$ for these two cases.  For the case $N=4$, the formula gives $927$.

An alternative explanation of the final formula using inclusion-exclusion: form a number of at most $N$ digits as follows:

- choose the first digit $A$, which must be non-zero;
- choose a digit $B$, different from $A$;
- form a string of between $0$ and $N-1$ $A$s and $B$s;
- join the one-digit string $A$ to this string.

There are $9\cdot9\cdot(2^N-1)$ strings of digits that may be formed in this way.  Strings that make no use of the digit $B$ have been counted $9$ times each, when they should only be counted once.  So subtract these $8$ times each.  There are $9N$ such strings ($9$ choices of the digit $A$ and $N$ possible lengths).  Hence the need to subtract $8\cdot9N$.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I ignore the digit $0$. You will have to figure that out yourself. But here is the answer to the question "how many positive integer less than $10000$ have at most two different digits and no $0$ in them":

There are $2^4 = 16$ four-digit numbers containing only the digits $1$ and $2$. The same for all other of the $\binom{9}{2}=\frac{9\cdot8}{2} = 36$ combinations of $2$ of the $9$ possible digits. If you add all those together, you will have counted the number "1111" and "2222" and so on too often. In fact you counted them each $8$ times, so you have to substract 7 again. This is called the inclusion-exclusion-principle.

The answer therefore is
$36\cdot16 - 9\cdot 7$.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 digit there are 9 options.
For 2 digits there are 9 $\cdot$ 10 options, since you can include 0 on the second option.
For 3 digits there are 9 $\cdot$ 10 $\cdot$ 2 options since you can repeat either one
For 4 digits there are 9 $\cdot$ 10 $\cdot$ 2 $\cdot$ 2 options. 
Add them up and you get 639 options.

Comment: What if your first and second digits are not distinct?